# Regexp change words that arent between " "

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace words that aren't between quotes.

how should work:

"hero"-not change

"Super hero you are" - not change

I am hero - change

You are super hero - change

I tried

`word = word.replaceAll("(?!\")(.*)hero(.*)(?!\")","$1 zero $2")` - but it doesn't work

Comment: I think thi is a reasonable question.  But the answer is that you can't (or shouldn't) do it with the regular expressions.

Comment: @MK.: I don't see a question. I see a statement "_I want..._". Not a single question mark used, no research presented and no failed attempts visible.

Comment: @MK.: You can easily make it with a regex!

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: can you have lookbehind and lookahead in one (java) regular expression?

Comment: @jlordo: you don't need to use lookarounds to do that. Lookarounds are a false good idea.

Comment: I believe this question is very badly formulated, but OP is simply asking how to replace a word in a `String` (and has somewhat convinced him/herself that regex needs to be involved). Which in fact would only involve the `replace` method of `String`.

Comment: @Mena: this would not work with `replace()`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte well show us how to do it then?

Comment: @jlordo I think it depends on how you interpret the question (yes we are reading chicken entrails). As in: `"I am super \"hero\" here and now".replace("hero", "zero")`

Comment: @jlordo so the question is not formulated well, but it is absolutely clear what the person is asking and it is not a trivial question.  I don't think it is right to concentrate on the formatting details.

Comment: @MK.: perhaps if the post will reopen.

Comment: @Mena the problem is that replace will not work. because it don't care if word is between quotes, or isn't.

Comment: @user2529782 aHA. Then I interpreted your question the **exact opposite** way :D And yes, lookahead and lookbehind can peacefully coexist within the same regex. Edit: although not really needed here either.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte why wait for the question to reopen?

Comment: @user2529782 wait. You edited your answer. So you don't care if the word is between quotes or if it isn't. You just want it replaced? Then use the `replace` method. In case I'm just going crazy, and you **do** want to replace the word only if not between quotes, then regex it is.  I'm getting a headache here.

Comment: @Mena Sorry. Yes I want to replace word only then when it isn't between quotes. Writing regex for changing words that are between quotes is easy, but for words that aren't is to hard for me.

Comment: Gee this thing keeps on changing. I give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you:

```
hero(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)
```

**Explanation:** 
Which basically means match a literal text (`hero`) if it is followed by even number of double quotes in other words match a desired text if it is outside double quotes.

**Testing:**

```
String str = "hero \"dont-hero\"";
String repl = str.replaceAll("hero(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)", "FOO");
//repl = FOO "dont-hero"
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/BXJxpw

Comment: @MK. Hope you have seen my working demo. In your link I see an unbalanced double quote which is not as per the OP's requirements.

Comment: @anubhava I downvoted because your solution uses regular expressions to solve a problem which is not well suited for regular expressions, the expression is hard to read and modify and it fails on the demonstrated example with unbalanced quotes.

Comment: @MK. Unbalanced quote is clearly your requirement not OP's requirement as OP's has readily marked this answer as accepted. This answer is also specific to OP's problem only not a general purpose tool to solve generic problems of this nature.

Comment: @anubhava I don't understand what an unbalanced quote even means in this context.  I would not -1 your answer if you were not 47K, but with such high rating, I don't feel like I need to constrain my distrust of regular expressions used to solve the wrong problem for the sake of being polite.  I do agree though that your regular expression is wizardly.

Comment: @anubhava I mean, I don't understand what makes you think that the quotes will be balanced.

Comment: @MK. I didn't intent to create wizardly regex it is just the specific nature of the problem needed this. As again this solves a very specific problem. OP's title, all the cited examples and finally his acceptance of this answer indicate that my interpretation wasn't too bad.

Comment: Hey @MK. At least don't punish me for high rating. Its been hard earned I swear :P

Comment: @anubhava sure, if you feel strongly about it, I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @anubhava yeah, I keep forgetting that moronic system doesn't allow me to take away the downvote, but allows me to edit and then take it away.  Stupid.

Comment: @MK. Ah yes I know about this. Have rarely downvoted but long time back I had to do same trick. Appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  Do you want to handle arbitrary number of nested quotes?  And if so, how?  For example, what do you want to happen with the following input?

```
I hate it when people say "you are such a "hero"!"
```

Is the word "hero" in quotes here?  or is the phrase "you are such a " in quotes, followed by the unquoted word "hero", followed by "!" in quotes?

But even a simpler case of

```
"hello" said the boring old "cat", are you really a "hero"?
```

is probably not achievable with regular expressions, at least not in a sane way that would make it worthwhile.

The accepted answer fails in a completely non-intuitive way on

```
I will be your "hero" baby! O"RLY?
```

Why don't you just parse the string with some code?

I feel that the following is a better choice than using regular expressions:

```
class Main {
  public static String replace(String str, String origstr, String newstr) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int lastIdx = 0; 
    boolean inquotes = false;      
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == '"') {
        if (inquotes) {
          inquotes = false;
          result.append(str.substring(lastIdx, i+1));
        } else {
          result.append(str.substring(lastIdx, i+1).replace(origstr, newstr));
          inquotes = true;
        }
        lastIdx = i+1;
      }
    }
    result.append(str.substring(lastIdx, str.length()).replace(origstr, newstr));
    return result.toString();
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println(replace("", "change", "___")); 
    System.out.println(replace("\"dont-change\"", "change", "___"));
    System.out.println(replace("\"change", "change", "___"));       
    System.out.println(replace("simple: change", "change", "___"));       
    System.out.println(replace("simple2: \"dont-change\"", "change", "___"));       
    System.out.println(replace("change \"dont-change\"\"", "change", "___"));       
    System.out.println(replace("change \"dont-change\"", "change", "___"));       
    System.out.println(replace("\"dont-change\" change", "change", "___"));        
  }
}
```

Comment: Your concerns are genuine but it still smells like a long comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @anubhava 1) too many comments already 2) I'm planning to add code here

Answer (score 0):

A way using regex.

the idea is to match all the substrings between quotes before the target word that i put in a capture group. Then with the capture group offset, i replace the substring containing the target word.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class quotyquot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "I am super hero here and now\n"
                     +"Superman is an incredible hero\n"
                     +"I am super \"hero\" here and now\n"
                     +"\"I am super hero here and now\"";
        String t = "hero";  // target
        String r = "zero";  // replacement
        Integer d = r.length() - t.length();
        Integer o = 0; // offset

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]*\"|(" + t + ")");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()) {
            if (m.group(1)!=null) {
               s= s.substring(0, m.start() - o) + r + s.substring(m.end() - o);
               o -= d;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Another way using split:

```
String t = "hero";  // target
String r = "zero";  // replacement
int c=0; // switch
String[] pi = s.split("(?=hero|\")|(?<=hero|\")");
String result = "";
for (int i=0; i<pi.length;i++) {
    if (c==0 && pi[i].equals(t))
        pi[i]=r;
    else if (pi[i].equals("\""))
        c = 1 - c;
    result += pi[i];
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: OK, so this is not a regular expression solution.  This is a combination of coding and regular expressions.